# write death test to verify std::set_terminate behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, googletest

I'm using gtest to write some unit tests for exception handling code. As a simple example, let's say I want my program to `abort` on any unhandled exception, so I create the following test:

```
TEST_F(myFixture, myTest)
{
    std::set_terminate([](){std::abort(); });

    EXPECT_DEATH(throw std::runtime_error("terminate"), ".*");
}
```

I would expect this to succeed, since `abort` should be called on the program. However, my actual result is:

> error: Death test: throw std::runtime_error("terminate")
>
> Result: threw an exception.
>   Error msg:
>
> [  DEATH   ]
>   [  DEATH   ] main.cpp(122):: Caught std::exception-derived exception escaping the
>   death test statement. Exception message: terminate
>
> [  DEATH   ]

I think gtest's exception handlers are getting in the way. I've tried disabling them using the `GTEST_CATCH_EXCEPTIONS` environment variable, and the `--gtest_catch_exceptions=0` command line flag as mentioned in [the advanced guide](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#exception-assertions), but I get the same result.

Am I doing something wrong, or is "death by exception" not something gtest can test for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong, or is "death by exception" not something gtest can test for?

What you're doing is wrong, *because* "death by exception" is not something gtest can test for.

```
EXPECT_DEATH(statement, regex);
```

verifies that `statement` calls `abort` or `exit` and causes output matching
`regex`. The statement `throw std::runtime_error("terminate")` doesn't call
`abort` or `exit`, as can be seen from the possibility of catching any exception in the program and letting it carry on. *If an exception is not caught* then the runtime library will call `terminate`, ending the program one way or another. But this outcome is not determined by any `throw` statement.

See the [documentation of death-tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md),
in particular:

> ...any test that checks that a program terminates (except by throwing an exception) 
>   in an expected fashion is also a death test.
>
> Note that if a piece of code throws an exception, we don't consider it "death" 
>   for the purpose of death tests, as the caller of the code could catch the 
>   exception and avoid the crash. If you want to verify exceptions thrown by your 
>   code, see Exception Assertions.

and:

> Note that a death test only cares about three things:
>
> 1. does statement abort or exit the process?
>      ...

I appreciate you may be oversimplfying your real issue here but you
hardly need to test that unhandled exceptions will result in `terminate`
being called, or that `terminate` will call the operative terminate-
handler, unless it is your daunting duty to test the implementation of
your compiler and standard library. Maybe more of the real issue should
be aired?

**Later**

> my problem with this is my program doesn't (or shouldn't) carry on. 
>   It should abort via the termination handler.

It should, but per documentation the expectation that your program should
not carry on *is not tested by* `EXPECT_DEATH` *on any* `throw` *statement*, because no `throw` statement terminates the program.

> What I really want to test is that the behavior of my set_terminate handler
>   is correct.

The behaviour of your `set_terminate` handler is correct if any only if,
having set that handler, a call to `std::terminate()` has the outcome you
expect. This question is independent of any `throw` statement and
you may test it like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <exception>


TEST(the_end, is_nigh)
{
    std::set_terminate([](){std::cout << "Goodbye cruel world\n", std::abort(); });

    EXPECT_DEATH(std::terminate(), ".*");
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

which produces:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from the_end
[ RUN      ] the_end.is_nigh
Goodbye cruel world
[       OK ] the_end.is_nigh (172 ms)
[----------] 1 test from the_end (172 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (172 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

Comment: What I really want to test is that the behavior of my `set_terminate` handler is correct, and that it's being invoked when I think it should be. In the real program it does several things (generates timestamps/stack traces) before finally calling `abort`.

Comment: "as can be seen from the possibility of catching any exception in the program and letting it carry on" ... my problem with this is my program doesn't (or shouldn't) carry on. It should `abort` via the termination handler.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus Updated in that light.